# I encountered this error while I am trying to run the anchor build command?

Tags: anchor, command

Error msg:

PS D:\solonacontracts\solana-counter> anchor build
Failed to obtain package metadata: cargo metadata exited with an error: error: failed to load manifest for workspace member \?\D:\solonacontracts\solana-counter\programs*

Caused by:
failed to read \?\D:\solonacontracts\solana-counter\programs*\Cargo.toml

Caused by:
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (os error 123)

Answer (score 1):

Check the contents of your `Cargo.toml` file. It seems there is a typo in there. There is some `program*` in there where it should be `program`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems this issue arises because you are using windows. I suggest running on a WSL or linux machine. You can check [here](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/issues/1992)

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/169/anchor-build-fails-with-error-failed-to-load-manifest-for-workspace-member/183#183) for Windows troubleshooting of Anchor.

In a nutshell, your `HOME` directory isn't set in a PowerShell terminal - which VS Code uses by default on Windows.